# Bitcore explorer insight testnet initialisation

Tags: transactions, bitcoin-core

I am using bitcore explorer and I want to initialize insight api in testnet.
It has the following code.
I try `var insight = new Insight('testnet')` but it is not working.
What value for url should i input so that  `Networks.get(url) === testnet`

```
function Insight(url, network) {
  if (!url && !network) {
    return new Insight(Networks.defaultNetwork);
  }
  if (Networks.get(url)) {
    network = Networks.get(url);
    if (network === Networks.livenet) {
      url = 'https://insight.bitpay.com';
    } else {
      url = 'https://test-insight.bitpay.com';
    }
  }
  JSUtil.defineImmutable(this, {
    url: url,
    network: Networks.get(network) || Networks.defaultNetwork
  });
  this.request = request;
  return this;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
const bitcore = require("bitcore-lib");
const Insight = require("bitcore-explorers").Insight;
insight = new Insight(bitcore.Networks.testnet);
```

then do the rest.